# Setup environment using script in Visual Studio Code

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I use remote development in Visual Studio Code for a C++/CMake project. However I need to setup a proper build environment before running cmake.

I know I can setup the environment manually by adding each variable to settings.json, but this is not really viable for me since there are a lot of variables that change frequently.

Is there a way I can have Visual Studio Code source a script before running CMake or automate this in any other way?

Comment: Have you looked at the `tasks.json` which can run any shell script where you can source variables and everything?

Comment: You could also automate the construction or modification of settings.json.

Answer (score 1):

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
sudo install -o root -g root -m 644 microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'